# Theming the userpage

Tags: theming, users

I want to modify the userpages with some changes:

1. change the page-title
2. hide some or all of the local taks items (the tabs)
3. display some user-infos
4. insert a view

Here is how I want to solve it:

1. use [THEMENAME_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6) to change the title
2. use [THEMENAME_menu_local_task()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_local_tasks/6) to hide the tabs
3. use the [user-profile.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user-profile.tpl.php/6) to display user infos
4. create a view and use [views_embed_view()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--views.module/function/views_embed_view/6)

Is there a better way of doing that? Should I consider using `page--user.tpl.php` or a combination?

Edit: concerns Drupal 6

Comment: Regarding point 2: do you just want to hide the tabs, or make the underlying pages inaccessible?

Comment: Hiding them should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, THEMENAME_preprocess_page() is fine for this, but one could argue that it's better to implement [hook_user](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_user/6) when $op == 'view'. That way you would make the change available for all themes (who knows you will be adding a mobile theme a couple of months from now?).
2. I wouldn't use THEMENAME_menu_local_tasks() for this, but instead do `$variables['tabs'] = '';` in THEMENAME_preprocess_page(). Of course, only do this for the user page, otherwise you will lose the tabs on all pages.
3. Yes, use user-profile.tpl.php to print out variables. If you need additional variables, fetch them in THEMENAME_preprocess_page() and add them to the $variables array to make them available in your template. Depending on what you need to do, see also [user-profile-category.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user-profile-category.tpl.php/6), [user-profile-item.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user-profile-item.tpl.php/6) and their respective preprocess functions.
4. Yes, that's an option. You can also create a block display of that view and enable the block on the user page.

I recommend not to use multiple page templates (like page-user.tpl.php) if you can. When you do, a simple change to page.tpl.php will often need to be applied to all other page templates as well, which is a bore.

Answer (score 0):

To change the title for profile page use [hook_username_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_username_alter/7), or the other method as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: That hook doesn't change only the title of the profile page: It changes the username that is shown for the user, in every place where the username is shown.